# Permutation with repetition and restriction

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 5 red flowers, 4 blue flowers and 4 green ones. I must plant them so that no 2 red flowers are planted near each other.

So I took all the possibilities (13!) and subtracted the ones where two flowers are near each other (2!11!) - 13! - 2!11!. I think I miss that other 3 red flowers can group, is my solution correct?

Comment: Are flowers of the same colour distinguishable?  If they are not, the answer is $\binom{8}{4}\binom{9}{5}$.

Comment: no they are not, can you elaborate in an answer why is it so?

Comment: I don't know what "no they are not" means. It is best if you say explicitly "distinguishable" (if they are) or  "indistinguishable". If they are distinguishable, we need to multiply what I wrote by $5!4!4!$.

Comment: indistinguishable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us arrange the $4$ blue and $4$ green in a row. Just considering these flowers, the positions of the blues can be chosen in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways.

These $8$ flowers determine $9$ "gaps" ($7$ real gaps, and $2$ "gaps" at the ends. We must choose $5$ of these gaps to slip a red into. We can choose the gaps in $\binom{9}{5}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{8}{4}\binom{9}{5}$ arrangements.